# Choosing debit card: MasterCard Debit or Visa Electron?

Tags: debit-card, mastercard, visa

What to take into account when choosing ***debit*** card for my personal account, between **MasterCard Debit** and **Visa Electron**?

Should I take into account for example possible international travel (EU vs US)?  Both types have the same popularity in my country (Poland).

Answer (score 6):

If it is anything like here in the United States there is no real difference between the two from a consumer perspective (except at most whether your bank issues Visa or Mastercard as a debit card, although Visa debit is the most common).

When it comes to using them abroad they both act the same. As long as there is a Visa logo (if you've chosen Visa/Visa Electron) or a Mastercard logo you'll get the same ability to use the card as if it were a native issued card.

So you should be able to focus your choice on the issuing bank and how well either method would work in your country.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's going to make much of a difference - both types of cards work fine in the US and EU IME.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still the case anymore, but in the UK Visa Electron and Visa Debit used to be different things. A lot of places would only take Visa Debit.

Aside from that I'm not aware of any differences between Visa and Mastercard as far as debit cards are concerned. In my experience Visa Debit cards seem to be more common.

Comment: It's about **MasterCard** Debit, not **Visa** Debit, and Visa Electron (that is what mBank offers free of any charges)

Comment: In the UK we have Visa Debit card _and_ Visa Electron cards. Those are what I was referring to.